# Remove FileDownload Dialog in WebBrowser VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, file, browser, dialog, download

I just need to remove/block this FileDownload Dialog:
(I don't have enough reputation to post images, so here is a link):
http://i60.tinypic.com/9bbwig.jpg

How can I do it?
Because I want to download file without this dialog, but when I use WebClient is starts up either. When I use My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile it freezes the WebBrowser (dialog doesn't show) and then if I use Background Worker (not to freeze the WebBrowser) the dialog shows...
I have no ideas what to do next :(

Comment: The following WebBrowser should be useful. You can cancel the file download either via the NavigatingExtended event or probably via the DownloadBegin event: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13598/Extended-NET-WebBrowser-Control | Events: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13598/Extended-NET-WebBrowser-Control#CreateDWebBrowserEvents2

Answer (score 0):

To download the logo of CNN you can use the following code

```
Imports System.Net

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Down_NewProp.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("http://edition.cnn.com/.a/1.97.4/assets/" & "logo_cnn_badge_3up.png"), Application.StartupPath & "\" & "logo_cnn.png")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I know this answer was written a long time ago, but what does downloading the CNN logo have to do with his question?

Answer (score -1):

It's a security device, to prevent the user download a file without realising.  I doubt you would be able to remove it.

Comment: I can do it via My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile method, but the program freezes.

Comment: You are able to stop it from showing using the above WebBrowser that I linked too.